# Web service in clustered environment

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl, webservice-client

I have a web service running on two clusters and the loadbalancer decides where to forward the requests. Because of firewall rules the client machine can see the loadbalancer only and the two application servers can not see the loadbalancer. I have the following wsdl files on clusters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-hudson-10-. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://contract.company-europe.com/" name="contractServiceService"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
             xmlns:tns="http://contract.company-europe.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
             xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="contractAgreementServicePortBinding_getcontractAgreement_WSAT_Policy"
                xmlns:wsat="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat">
        <wsat:ATAlwaysCapability/>
        <wsat:ATAssertion wsp:Optional="true" ns2:Optional="true"
                          xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy"/>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://contract.company-europe.com/"
                        schemaLocation="schemaLocation="http://loadbalancer/merlin/contractAgreementService?wsdl&resource=contractAgreementServiceService_schema.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getcontractAgreement">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getcontractAgreement"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getcontractAgreementResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getcontractAgreementResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="IOException">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:IOException"/>
    </message>

    <message name="MerlinBaseException">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:MerlinBaseException"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="contractAgreementService">
        <operation name="getcontractAgreement">
            <input wsam:Action="http://contract.company-europe.com/contractAgreementService/getcontractAgreementRequest"
                   message="tns:getcontractAgreement"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://contract.company-europe.com/contractAgreementService/getcontractAgreementResponse"
                    message="tns:getcontractAgreementResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:IOException" name="IOException"
                   wsam:Action="http://contract.company-europe.com/contractAgreementService/getcontractAgreement/Fault/IOException"/>
            <fault message="tns:MerlinBaseException" name="MerlinBaseException"
                   wsam:Action="http://contract.company-europe.com/contractAgreementService/getcontractAgreement/Fault/MerlinBaseException"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="contractAgreementServicePortBinding" type="tns:contractAgreementService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="getcontractAgreement">
            <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#contractAgreementServicePortBinding_getcontractAgreement_WSAT_Policy"/>
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#contractAgreementServicePortBinding_getcontractAgreement_WSAT_Policy"/>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#contractAgreementServicePortBinding_getcontractAgreement_WSAT_Policy"/>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="IOException">
                <soap:fault name="IOException" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
            <fault name="MerlinBaseException">
                <soap:fault name="MerlinBaseException" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="contractAgreementServiceService">
        <port name="contractAgreementServicePort" binding="tns:contractAgreementServicePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://loadbalancer/merlin/contractAgreementService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Is it correct that the soap address and the xsd is pointing to the loadbalancer or should they use the local cluster1/cluster2 address?

**UPDATE1**

Unfortunately I got the following error message. This happens in clustered environment only:

```
2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:100) -  - REQUEST URI       =/merlin/contractAgreementService
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:101) -  -           authType=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:102) -  -  characterEncoding=utf-8
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:103) -  -      contentLength=273
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:104) -  -        contentType=text/xml; charset=utf-8
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:105) -  -        contextPath=/merlin
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=content-type=text/xml; charset=utf-8
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=soapaction="http://rental.company-europe.com/contractAgreementService/getContractAgreementRequest"
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=host=loadbalancer
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=content-length=273
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=expect=100-continue
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:118) -  -             header=connection=Keep-Alive
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:121) -  -             locale=en_GB
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:122) -  -             method=POST
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:134) -  -          parameter=wsdl=
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:136) -  -           pathInfo=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:137) -  -           protocol=HTTP/1.1
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:138) -  -        queryString=wsdl
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:139) -  -         remoteAddr=10.101.98.79
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:140) -  -         remoteHost=10.101.98.79
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:141) -  -         remoteUser=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:142) -  - requestedSessionId=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:143) -  -             scheme=http
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:144) -  -         serverName=loadbalancer
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:145) -  -         serverPort=80
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:146) -  -        servletPath=/contractAgreementService
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:147) -  -           isSecure=false
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:148) -  - ---------------------------------------------------------------
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] DEBUG (org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageContextAssociation:46) -  - pushMessageContext: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.handler.SOAPMessageContextJAXWS@77c1ca7 (Thread http-FXPEARLAP2%2F10.101.117.5-58080-2)
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] DEBUG (org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl:215) -  - createMessage: [contentType=text/xml; charset=utf-8]
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] DEBUG (org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.EndpointMetaData:732) -  - Configure SOAPBinding
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,937] ERROR (org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS:149) -  - SOAP request exception
java.io.IOException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:763)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:792)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:703)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:297)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
    at org.jboss.wsf.common.IOUtils.copyStream(IOUtils.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:447)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] DEBUG (org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS:269) -  - Cannot obtain fault meta data for: class java.io.IOException
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] DEBUG (org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageContextAssociation:75) -  - popMessageContext: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.handler.SOAPMessageContextJAXWS@77c1ca7 (Thread http-FXPEARLAP2%2F10.101.117.5-58080-2)
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:154) -  - ---------------------------------------------------------------
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:155) -  -           authType=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:156) -  -      contentLength=-1
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:157) -  -        contentType=text/xml;charset=UTF-8
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:168) -  -             header=X-Powered-By=Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)/JBossWeb-2.0
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:168) -  -             header=Content-Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:168) -  -             header=Transfer-Encoding=chunked
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,953] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:168) -  -             header=Date=Thu, 03 Nov 2011 09:43:21 GMT
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,968] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:168) -  -             header=Connection=close
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,968] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:170) -  -            message=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,968] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:171) -  -         remoteUser=null
[2011-11-03 09:43:21,968] INFO  (org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]:172) -  -             status=500
```

Do you know what it means? I put some logs into the contract service itself and I do not see them, so there might be some problems with the request?

Comment: Doesn't this line look strange? `schemaLocation="schemaLocation="http://loadbalancer/merlin/contractAgreementService?wsdl&resource=contractAgreementServiceService_schema.xsd"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct. Because this abstracts the fact that you have a loadbalancer and you can actually add more and more nodes in the future without changing anything

Answer (score 0):

You said that your application servers can't access loadbalancer. Could it be that your cluster nodes are trying to reach loadbalancer for the schemalocation and fail to do that?

If that's the problem you could try to use a relative URI for your schemalocation.

Also you could try fixing the `schemaLocation="schemaLocation="http:...` string.